# Safe navigation with Object to Decimal in Map<String,Object>

Tags: apex

Today I was shown a code I though could use some Safe navigation improvement, after some tries I don't understand how to apply safe navigation in this scenario with an Object that has to be converted to Decimal.

```
Map<String,Object> testMap =new Map<String,Object> {'field1'=>null,'field2'=>3.3};

// This has to be refactored using safe navigation
Decimal new_decimal = testMap.get('field1') != null?  ((Decimal)testMap.get('field1').set_scale(2)):null
```

I tried something like

```
Decimal new_decimal = (Decimal)testMap.get('field1')?.set_scale(2);
```

But I get

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void set_scale(Integer) from the type Object

How can I get my expected result using Safe navigation?

Comment: Can you try to surround your cast before the safe-navigator?
`Decimal new_decimal = ((Decimal)testMap.get('field1'))?.set_scale(2);`

Comment: I tried it, same error.

Comment: Fair enough, what about storing `(Decimal) testMap.get('field1')` first in a variable and then using the safe-navigator? I'm assuming this might be a corner case of safe-navigator not yet covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to use it is the following one

```
Decimal new_decimal = ((Decimal) testMap.get('field1'))?.setScale(2);
```

which has been suggested already. The problem is the method that you were using as set_scale() is not a method, it is setScale().